# Java WS won't start the application until other running javaws dead instances are killed

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I'm developing applications using Java and deploying them using Java Web Start. I'm developing with Mac OS and testing under Windows XP and 7.
I'm getting a strange issue, only on 7 as it seems.

The `javaws.exe` process somehow fails, and I cannot start the application again. Every time I click on the desktop icon my JNLP has created, it spawns another `javaws.exe` process but nothing happens, my code won't run, not even the first line of the `public static void main` program entry point.

I tried to launch it from command-line, but I don't get any log or any error message that could help me fix this.
I tried to launch [another JNLP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html), it worked like a charm!

Killing all the `javaws.exe` running instances fixes the issue, but I can not expect my customers to do that.

So it means that somehow I am having an issue with my application which makes java fail.
I just ran into this: the app was launched, I clicked the red cross to close it, and opened it again (I changed the server side jars and jnlp files). It didn't open and I couldn't open it again until I killed all `javaws.exe` instances.

Here's some details:

- developed under Mac OS X.7
- tested under Windows 7
- ran with Java 7
- application is developed with Eclipse, has a SWT UI and several other third party libraries
- I turned on all logging from the [Java control panel item](http://www.robonekp.com/2007/02/how-do-i-enable-java-tracing-on-client.html)

Here's the Java console contents, which popped up when I ran the JNLP mentioned above:

```
Java Web Start 10.9.2.05
Using JRE version 1.7.0_09-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Bicou
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
p:   reload proxy configuration
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
    Match: beginTraversal
Match: digest selected JREDesc: JREDesc[version 1.6+, heap=-1--1, args=null, href=http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se, sel=false, null, null], JREInfo: JREInfo for index 0:
    platform is: 1.7
    product is: 1.7.0_09
    location is: http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
    path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
    args is: null
    native platform is: Windows, x86 [ x86, 32bit ]
    JavaFX runtime is: JavaFX 2.2.3 found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\
    enabled is: true
    registered is: true
    system is: true

    Match: ignoring maxHeap: -1
    Match: ignoring InitHeap: -1
    Match: digesting vmargs: null
    Match: digested vmargs: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: JVM args after accumulation: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: digest LaunchDesc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/deployment/webstart/ex6/webstart_ComponentArch_DynamicTreeDemo/dynamictree-webstart.jnlp
    Match: digest properties: []
    Match: JVM args: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: endTraversal ..
    Match: JVM args final: 
    Match: Running JREInfo Version    match: 1.7.0.09 == 1.7.0.09
     Match: Running JVM args match: have:<>  satisfy want:<>
```

My JNLP:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+"
    codebase="http://my.url/"
    href="UpCab.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>UpCab</title>
        <vendor>Benoit Duffez</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://my.url/" />
        <description>Logiciel de gestion de cabinet</description>
        <icon href="icon.png" kind="shortcut" />
        <icon href="splash.png" kind="splash" />
        <offline-allowed />
        <shortcut online="true" install="true">
            <desktop />
        </shortcut>
    </information>

    <security>
        <all-permissions />
    </security>

    <resources>
        <jar href="opencsv-2.3.jar" />
        <jar href="iText-2.1.7.jar" />
        <jar href="iTextRTF.jar" />
        <jar href="sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" />
        <jar href="commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" />
        <jar href="httpclient-4.2.jar" />
        <jar href="upcab.jar" />
        <jar href="httpcore-4.2.jar" />
        <jar href="jna.jar" />
        <jar href="platform.jar" />
    </resources>

    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href="swt-win32-x86.jar" />
    </resources>

    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href="swt-win32-x86_64.jar" />
    </resources>

    <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href="swt-win32-x86_64.jar" />
    </resources>

    <resources os="Mac" arch="x86_64">
        <j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-XstartOnFirstThread" />
        <nativelib href="swt-mac-x86_64.jar" />
    </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="my.full.pkg.Main" />
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Ideally, these "dead" processes should die by themselves. Is it possible to fix that instead?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: that's the idea, yes.

Comment: The JNLP appears to be valid, but check it with [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) in any case.

Comment: Does your application use a SingleInstance Service: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/SingleInstanceService.html?

Comment: @AkselWillgert: I was just commenting out the code related to this. I do use it and I do think it may be the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crashed JavaWebStart application that has started the [SingleInstanceService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/SingleInstanceService.html) might leave the SingleInstanceService running, that will keep picking up any subsequent attempts to launch the same application again. Adding a log-message to the Listener is recomended. Note, the log-message would show in the console of the first application, and not the one just being launched.

```
private class SingleInstance implements SingleInstanceListener {
    @Override
    public void newActivation(final String[] params) {
        logger.info("newActivation params=" + params);

        ... activation code here ...

    }
}
```

Make sure to stop all running threads and remove registered SingleInstanceListeners if the application crashes.

```
SingleInstanceService sis = (SingleInstanceService) ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.SingleInstanceService");
sis.removeSingleInstanceListener(mySingleInstanceListener);
```

Comment: That was it. Smart guess :)